# iphone- tableview number inserting

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
{
  .....
 result *temp = [suff objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSLog(@"%@", temp.pid);
 cell.pidlab.text = temp.pid;
 ......
}
```

there was a problem that pid is print in console window as number but there is not assign in table cell i have a error message..

how to solve it?

```
[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x688dae0
2012-03-13 14:14:31.161 secondDemo1[1978:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x688dae0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13be052 0x154fd0a 0x13bfced 0x1324f00 0x1324ce2 0x15368f 0x34c0 0xaee0f 0xaf589 0x9adfd 0xa9851 0x54301 0x13bfe72 0x1d6892d 0x1d72827 0x1cf8fa7 0x1cfaea6 0x1d8630c 0x26530 0x13929ce 0x1329670 0x12f54f6 0x12f4db4 0x12f4ccb 0x12a7879 0x12a793e 0x15a9b 0x21c8 0x2125)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

Comment: FYI, multiple question/exclamation marks **do not** help to get answer faster

Comment: @sai-info.iphone You should upvote helpful questions and mark the most helpful as the accepted answer.

Comment: As far as my opinion, you are assigning number to label...so u have to assign pid with stringWithFormat.....I am probable..ok.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pid` is not an `NSString` type of variable.
You need to use:

```
cell.pidlab.text = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%d",[temp.pid intValue]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely problem is you're trying to set label's text property to something that is not a NSString (NSNumber from error description).

So you need to convert your value to string before set it to the label:

```
cell.pidlab.text = [temp.pid stringValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a `NSNumber` (__NSCFNumber is a NSNumer) to an `NSString`. 
Try this instead

```
cell.pidlab.text = [temp.pid stringValue];
```

Comment: ya thats work but there is in after scroll the all number assign is same ?? why ?

Comment: @Vladimir of course NSNumber may not necessarily be an int. Updated again.